# Change value within a df1 column according to another df

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would need help in order to change column values within a **df2** according to col values in another **df1**

Here is the **df1** :

```
    COL1 NB                                                                                                 COL2
1   G1   10 [scaffold_17139_1441-2314_-__Felis_cattus,scaffold_4202_2-BLOCs_+__Canis_lupus,scaffold_6677_+__Canis_lupus]
2   G1   3                                                                             [scaffod_4__Canis_lupus]
3   G2   3                             [scaffold_6677_1441-2314_-__Felis_cattus,AA_2_3_2-BLOCs_+__Felis_cattus]
```

as you can see some `COL2 element` have  `Nb-BLOCs` patterns, for instance :

```
`scaffold_4202_2-BLOCs_+__Canis_lupus` or  `AA_2_3_2-BLOCs_+__Felis_cattus`
```

then the idea is to take the part before `Nb-BLOCs`(`COL3` in **df2**) and the part after `__` (`SP` in **df2**).

Then if there is a match in **df2** with these two elements, I add the `df1$NB` equivalent into the **df2**

here is the **df2**

```
  COL1 NB COL3          SP
1   G1  9 scaffold_4202 Canis_lupus
2   G2 19 AA_2_3        Felis_catus
3   G1 12 scaffold_4202 Felis_catus
```

Then if I change it I should then change only `df2$NB` **row1** and **row2** and get :

```
  COL1 NB  COL3           SP
1   G1 10  scaffold_4202 Canis_lupus
2   G2 3   AA_2_3        Felis_catus
3   G1 12  scaffold_4202 Felis_catus
```

**df1 data**

```
structure(list(COL1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("G1", 
                                                               "G2"), class = "factor"), NB = c(10L, 3L, 3L), COL2 = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                                                 1L, 3L), .Label = c("[scaffod_4__Canis_lupus]", "[scaffold_17139_1441-2314_-__Felis_catus,scaffold_4202_2-BLOCs_+__Canis_lupus,scaffold_6677_+__Canis_lupus]", 
                                                                                                                                                     "[scaffold_6677_1441-2314_-__Felis_cattus,AA_2_3_2-BLOCs_+__Felis_catus]"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        -3L))
```

**df2 data** :

```
structure(list(COL1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("G1", 
"G2"), class = "factor"), NB = c(9L, 19L, 12L), COL3 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("AA_2_3", "scaffold_4202"), class = "factor"), 
    SP = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Canis_lupus", "Felis_catus"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Does someone have an idea? thank you for yout time.

Edit from Ronak code

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(COL3 = str_match(COL2, regex(',(.*)_\\d+-BLOCs'))[, 2], 
         SP = str_extract(COL2, ',(.*)_\\d+-BLOCs_.__.*,|,(.*)_\\d+-BLOCs_.__.*]'),
         SP = gsub(',','',SP),
         SP = gsub(']','',SP),
         SP = gsub('.*__','',SP)
         ) %>%
  right_join(df2, by = c('COL1', 'COL3', 'SP')) %>%
  mutate(NB = coalesce(NB.x, NB.y)) %>%
  select(COL1, NB, COL3, SP)
```

Comment: It would be easier if you split your col2 into parts, so the answer could focus on the data joining and logic as opposed to data prep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the string required to match the two dataframes using `str_match`/`str_extract` and keep the `NB` values from `df1` if present.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(COL3 = str_match(COL2, ',(.*)_\\d+-BLOCs')[, 2], 
         SP = str_extract(COL2, 'SP\\d+')) %>%
  right_join(df2, by = c('COL1', 'COL3', 'SP')) %>%
  mutate(NB = coalesce(NB.x, NB.y)) %>%
  select(COL1, NB, COL3, SP)

#  COL1 NB          COL3  SP
#1   G1 10 scaffold_4202 SP2
#2   G2  3        AA_2_3 SP3
#3   G1 12 scaffold_4202 SP3
```

Comment: Thank you, now that I see your code I changed a little bit the dataframe (an espacially the SP names to fit better my real data), in fact I can have different species within same row and their name can be complex. Can you check please? Thank you very much

Comment: Well I added a regex solution with your code